# zsh: What does the command "time + number" do in zsh

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I type time + number in zsh:

```
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup/bin [10:01:49]
$ time 1
/tmp/atupal/setup/bin/lib/python2.7
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup/bin/lib/python2.7 [10:01:54]
$ time 2
/tmp/atupal/setup
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup [10:01:59]
$ time 3
/tmp/atupal/setup/app
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup/app [10:02:03]
$ time 3
/tmp/atupal/setup/bin
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup/bin [10:02:04]
$ time 3
/tmp/atupal/setup/bin/lib/python2.7
# atupal at local in /tmp/atupal/setup/bin/lib/python2.7 [10:02:05]
$
```

But when I type `time 10` is says `command not found: 10`

My zsh version is :zsh 5.0.2-4
And my `uname` result:`Linux 3.12.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 12 12:57:31 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What is the output of `type time`?

Comment: @llua It's `shell  6.18s user 1.30s system 0% cpu 94:49:14.83 total
children  13.11s user 2.25s system 0% cpu 94:49:14.83 total`.

Comment: It shouldn't of outputed that, try `whence -w time` or `builtin type time`

Comment: @llua Thanks. The output is "time is a reserved word", so what's it means?

Comment: the reserved word `time` doesn't behave the way you've shown in your question, i suspect you have an alias or something, if you run `zsh -f` then `time 1` you should get a error of the command `1` not being found and the time statistics.

Comment: @llua Right, after run `zsh -f` get the "command 1 not found" error.

Comment: So with the config that provides the output in your question, `print $aliases[time]` should output something since alias have higher priority over reserved words.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12130/discussion-between-atupal-and-llua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oh-my-zsh` creates a few alias in `.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh` named `1`, `2` ... `9` which expand to `cd -`, `cd -1`, etc. So time is functioning correctly, but the unexpected alias `1` actually does something. The reason why time's normal output isn't given is due to the fact `cd` is a builtin command that doesn't require forking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something else going on here with your `zsh` setup. I have a stock setup and when I run `time #` I get the expected results of `command not found: ..`

#### Example

```
$ time 1
zsh: command not found: 1
1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
$ time 2
zsh: command not found: 2
2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
$ time 3
zsh: command not found: 3
3  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
$ time 10
zsh: command not found: 10
10  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
```

Confirming which `time` we're using within our environment.

```
$ whence -w time
time: reserved

$ builtin time   
zsh: no such builtin: time
```

So the command `time` is being provided by `zsh` itself. I would suspect that you either have an alias or function that's overriding the default `time` command.

Say it were overridden with an alias then `whence -w time` would show it like this:

```
$ whence -w time 
time: alias
```

Here's another example using the `type` command which shows that I've overridden `time` as an alias & a function in addtion to several other methods. The `type` command with the `-a` switch reveals all of them.

```
$ type -a time
time is an alias for ls
time is a reserved word
time is a shell function
time is /usr/bin/time
time is /bin/time
```

#### Disabling zsh config files

You can invoke a `zsh` without reading your config files using the `-f` switch.

```
  -f    equivalent to --no-rcs
```

#### Example

```
$ zsh -f    
$ whence -w time
time: reserved
```

Comment: But `whence -w time` output `time: reserved`

Comment: @atupal - yes, I would suspect that `time` is being overridden in some other manner.